# Format Time from the json Result in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am trying to format the time from the `json` result. Here is my code

```
if (Object.keys(billNoData).length > 0) {
          for (var x in billNoData) {
               this.dayByBillNoExport.push({                                   
                     'Time': this.datePipe.transform(billNoData[x].BillTime, 'HH:mm'),                                    
                     })
               }
       }
```

I would like to have the time to stored in the array as `14:37.`

But I get the below error

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '14:37:04' for pipe 'DatePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (invalid_pipe_argument_error.ts:1)
at DatePipe.transform (date_pipe.ts:91)
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (sales.component.ts:273)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:190)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:80)
```

I have imported the `DatePipe` too.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the wrong arguments "HH:mm" in transform method. Please refer https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe link.

Comment: Should I need to pass 'shorttime'. I tried with that too but I get the same error. What should I pass in transform method?